# How can I configure git help to use Firefox?

Tags: git, macos, firefox

I was using Git on a Windows box and the git bash always used the web version for help.  I really liked this and I am trying to do the same on my mac.

I ran:

```
$ git config --global help.format web
$ git config --global web.browser firefox
```

and the output of a `help` command is:

```
$ The browser firefox is not available as 'firefox'.
```

I then set:

```
$ git config --global browser.firefox.path /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

Since I usually have firefox open, it now cries:

> A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time.

The real command I would like git to use is `open -a Firefox.app somefile`.  I tried setting `browser.firefox.cmd` with no avail.

My question: how can I configure git to use the web version and call/use firefox in a way that won't cause issue if it's already open?

Comment: What value did you set `browser.firefox.cmd` to, and did you still have `browser.firefox.path` set?

Comment: I was using `cmd = open -a Firefox.app` but I found a solution.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you can't override the command for a known browser.  What worked is using a browser name that is not `firefox`:

```
git config --global web.browser ff
git config --global browser.ff.cmd "open -a Firefox.app"
```

Comment: +1: Aha. Looking at the source, this is very obvious: there's a case (shell for `switch`) statement which checks several known browsers, and calls them with the configured path according to its known syntax, and only uses `browser.*.cmd` if none of the cases match, in which case it doesn't actually use browser.path... this is actually all documented in the `git-web--browse` manpage, which is a little inconsistent with the documentation for `git-config`.

Comment: The important bit is the line "you can't override the command for a known browser."

This solved a similar problem I was having loading Chrome. My config is now:

[web]
    browser = chr
[browser "chr"]
    cmd = /usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OS X user, but I suppose that the shell doesn't let you pass a multi-word argument without escaping it.

Edit directly your `~/.gitconfig` file and insert the following `[web]` section:

```
[web]
    browser = open -a Firefox.app
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work.  
  
I just discovered what does work is setting `web.browser` to `open`.  
  
I wish you solution worked because if you have `.html` files associated with a text editor instead of a browser, sad times.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out. Why don't you try to use another web browser like Google Chrome for browsing the docs?

Comment: @doug then why don't you answer to your own question and accept it? People who will seek for the solution of this problem will benefit from it.