# Git instaweb: The browser is not available

Tags: macos, git

I'm trying to setup `git instaweb` to open in Chrome. I have set the default browser like so:

```
git config --global web.browser chrome
```

This change is reflected in my global `.gitconfig`, and the [git-web--browse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-web--browse.html) documentation says that chrome is available as something to pass in.

When I run `git instaweb` this is what I get:

```
The browser chrome is not available as 'chrome'.
http://127.0.0.1:1234
```

I have also tried `google-chrome` and the same results happen. How can I set the web browser to actually open in chrome?

Running OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it needs a solution similar to [How can I configure git help to use Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948249/6309):

```
git config --global web.browser ch
git config --global browser.ch.cmd "open -a Google Chrome.app"
```

The [OP MishieMoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334934/mishiemoo) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285017/git-instaweb-the-browser-is-not-available/14298925#comment19912434_14298925) you need the full path:

```
git config --global browser.ch.cmd "open -a \"/Applications/Google Chrome.app\""
```

> Without the absolute path, it was trying to open `Chrome.app` in my current directory (which was not `Applications`)

Comment: This works with a slight modification:

`git config --global browser.ch.cmd "open -a \"/Applications/Google Chrome.app\""`

Without the absolute path, it was trying to open `Chrome.app` in my current directory (which was not Applications).

Comment: @MishieMoo Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.