# Git open Chrome for Help in Windows 7?

Tags: git, windows-7

I've set html files to open with Notepad++ by default (in Windows).

When I type something like `git help commit`, it uses Notepad++ to open the html manual page instead of Chrome.

I want to keep Notepad++ as the default html editor but I want Git to open manual/help pages in Chrome.  How can I do that?

I added this to my **.gitconfig** file:

```
[web]
    browser = googchr
[browser "googchr"]
    cmd = \"/C/Users/MY_USERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --new-window\"
```

I did it that way because something similar worked for this guy on Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948249/470749.

But for me, Notepad++ keeps opening instead of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This works for me in Git Bash on Windows 10

```
[web]
    browser = googchr
[browser "googchr"] 
    path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
```

Many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639359/470749!

Answer (score -1):

One way to get around this is to do

```
google-chrome (html file)
```

Where the html file is the address of the help file. You could even use a shortcut.

Did his following solution work for you?

```
git config --global web.browser ff
git config --global browser.ff.cmd "open -a Firefox.app"
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying "One way to get around this is to do `google-chrome (html file)`".  Exactly what should I type into my Git Bash?  Also, his solution (using `"open -a Firefox.app"`) is for Mac. Thanks.

Comment: I mean if you know the address of the help file, you can type google-chrome (ADDRESS), and call the browser by name. That may or may not help. Its possible that the git commands are identical for Mac and Win. I don't see why they wouldn't be.