# how to set google-chrome as git default browser

Tags: git, google-chrome

I want **GIT** to open the help pages in Chrome browser by default though the Windows 7 default browser is IE which I can't change for other reasons. I have added the following to the git config file.

```
[web]
    browser = chrome
[browser "chrome"]
    cmd = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/
```

But it still opens IE browser. In git's bash environment it gives the message `"Launching default browser to display HTML ..."`.  On Git Gui, it throws a lengthier message

```
The browser chrome is not available as 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/'.
The browser chrome is not available as 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/'.
    while executing
"exec {C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe} {C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-web--browse} {file:C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/doc/git/ht..."
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval exec $opt $cmdp $args"
    (procedure "git" line 23)
    invoked from within
"git "web--browse" $url"
    (procedure "start_browser" line 2)
    invoked from within
"start_browser {file:C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/doc/git/html/index.html}"
    (menu invoke)
```

Could someone help me resolve this?

**EDIT:** Also tried

```
[web]
    browser = chrome
[browser "chrome"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

Now I am able to open online documentation in chrome from Git Gui. But it does not work in git bash.

Comment: I know this is old but I too would like a solution to this. The answer below by @AshWilson doesn't seem to work for me either

Answer (score 12):

After a bit of trial and error, I found a working solution. My `.gitconfig` used by the Git bash (Windows 10, 64-bit, Git version 2.13.1.windows.2) looks like this:

```
[web]
    browser = "chrome"
[browser "chrome"]
    path = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
```

Which is the same as executing the following two commands:

1. `git config --global web.browser chrome` and then executing
2. `git config --global web.browser.chrome.path C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`

Please note the double backslashes and that there are neither single nor double quotes used although the path contains whitespaces. Setting the more unix-like value `/C/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe` does work, too. From my point of view, setting a value for `web.browser.chrome.cmd` seems to be ignored if `path` is also set. Defining `google-chrome` instead seems to be valid, too, because git still opened Google Chrome, confirming the information that can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-web--browse.html.

So, to answer the original question: If you want to use a windows-like value for `web.browser.chrome.path`, make sure to use double backslashes. If you're okay with a more unix-like value use `/C/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`.

Comment: your example `git config --global web.browser.chrome.path` results in a junk entry with `Git 2.19.1.windows.1`. I need to use `browser.chrome.path` (i.e. without the `web.` part) for receiving a proper entry. But +1 anyways since you pointed me to the right direction!

Answer (score 9):

Git is expecting the config setting `browser.<tool>.path` to point to the executable of a recognized browser, not the containing directory. `browser.<tool>.cmd` is only used if the browser you specify isn't on the list of recognized browsers (of which "chrome" is one). See the [git-web--browse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-web--browse.html#_configuration_variables) docs for details.

Try using this in your `.gitconfig` instead:

```
[web]
    browser = chrome
[browser "chrome"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

If you want to customize the command line that's used to launch Chrome, you can give it a name that *isn't* recognized as a supported browser, and specify the command in `cmd` instead:

```
[web]
    browser = specialchrome
[browser "specialchrome"]
    cmd = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --new-window
```

Comment: Hmmm. Does running `GIT_TRACE=1 git help log` show anything useful?

Comment: `$ GIT_TRACE=1 git help log
  trace: built-in: git 'help' 'log'
  Launching default browser to display HTML ...`

Comment: With changes you suggested, actually I am able to open help in chrome from Git Gui. But it does not work in git bash.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, you would want to use backslashes. E.g. my config looks like this.

```
web.browser=chrome
browser.chrome.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe
```

Also, I suggest you use the following (I presume this always ships with a git installation) to see if bash launches Chrome.

```
$ git help branch
```

You will receive fatal errors if the help file you are trying to see does not exist. E.g. on my system, trying the following results in an error.

```
$ git help packsizelimit

Launching default browser to display HTML ...
fatal: failed to launch browser for C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/doc/git/html//gitpacksizelimit.html
```

Usually, git is good with the error description. In my example, there is no gitpacksizelimit.html file at the location git checks for help files. Re-read the error and it should offer you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Ash Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908202/2123530)'s answer helpful:

> ```
> [web]
>     browser = chrome
> [browser "chrome"]
>     path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
> ```

To write directly to `.gitconfig` from bash I used:

```sh
git config --global browser."chrome".path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and it worked.

```
[web]
    browser = google-chrome
```

or try this:

```
$ git config --global web.browser google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution: go to the default apps (On the Start menu, select Settings > Apps > Default apps) and change your default browser to Chrome (default is IE).

Comment: You missed the part where OP clearly states "default browser is IE which I can't change for other reasons".

Answer (score 0):

You just set Chrome as the default browser, like so:

[image: Chrome settings -> Default browser]