# Git manpage opens in texteditor instead of browser

Tags: git, manpage

Somehow whenever I type `git <command> --help` which is supposed to open up the manpage for a given `<command>` in my browser it instead opens it up in my default text editor.

I'd assume it's a option or setting somewhere but I can't find anything weird or anything that has changed in `.gitconfig`.

I'd like to make it open it up in my default browser once again. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything about this particular problem. I did however find this [How can I configure git help to use Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947915/how-can-i-configure-git-help-to-use-firefox) but it's not the same as I wasnt trying to associate git with another browser than my default. git manpage wasnt displayed in a browser at all.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?  By the way, you didn't Google hard enough ^ ^.

Comment: You may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947915/how-can-i-configure-git-help-to-use-firefox

Comment: Im running windows. I found the link joran posted but ive never had to define this in my config file, it just worked out of the box until it didnt, so thats why i didnt think it was the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is embarrassing but I don't want to be *that* guy ([Obligatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/979/))

Somehow my default program associated with .html files got set to Sublime Text so when git tried to open the default program it did exactly as it was supposed too. Simply changing this to Chrome did the trick.